# Apache Beam Combine Function not doing anything

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use a simple Combine function for the first time applying fixed windows of 10 seconds. Currently I'm just printing out some logging as part of the transforms to see whether something is actually happening but it seems the transforms after the ExtractStreamingMeasures() never actually get called. I'm running the DirectRunner.

Am I missing something?

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
PubsubOptions dataflowOptions = options.as(PubsubOptions.class);
dataflowOptions.setStreaming(true);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p
            .apply(Window.<Txn>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(10))))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractStreamingMeasures()))
            .apply(Count.<String>perElement())
            .apply(ParDo.of(new DoSomething()));
```

Transforms:

```
static class ExtractStreamingMeasures extends DoFn<Txn, String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        System.out.println(c.element().getLocationId()); // <= this prints
        c.output(c.element().getLocationId());
    }
}

static class DoSomething extends DoFn<KV<String, Long>, KV<String, Long>> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        System.out.println(c.element()); // <= this doesn't print
        c.output(c.element());
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, this seems like it should work. Perhaps you could check the output some way other than `System.out.println`. But note that since you already did a `Count.perElement()` there will always be just a single input per key to `Combine.perKey(SumTransanctions)`.

Comment: @KennKnowles you're right, I've updated the example and simplified it to only do the out of the box Count function, same problem though. I don't know what better way to see whether something is happening than doing the Sysout as proper logging will obviously do to the same.

Comment: The behavior implies that the Count aggregation never fires. The default triggering will be one output when the watermark reaches the end of the window. So it is likely that never happens. It seems you have omitted your initial data source from the code snippet; this is where element timestamps and the watermark would come from.

Comment: I'm using a PubSub Source where messages get posted every other second. I've tried not setting a timestamp manually as I understood the default behavior is that a timestamp is assigned when read from the queue. I've also tried manually setting timestamps but both methods don't seem to trigger. I'm running this with the DirectRunner.

Answer (score 1):

Had to provide a different trigger in order for the window to fire properly. The following code will trigger an output every 10 seconds for a window size of 10 minutes.

```
p.apply("AssignToWindow", Window.<Txn>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(10)))
                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(10))))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes()
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(1)))
```